# jQuery UI Autocomplete - How to handle AJAX errors?

Tags: jquery-ui, error-handling

I'm using the jQuery Autocomplete control to autocomplete from the server via an AJAX call.
I implemented the search event to show a "Loading..." animation while results are being fetched from the server.
I want to disable that animation and show a message if fetching the autocomplete results from the server failed (timeout or whatever)
Whats the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a looksie at the jQuery.ajaxError method, which allows you to setup a default error callback for all ajax calls; http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: thats a global handler... how do I handle the autocomplete's call specifically?

Comment: I guess you're using source: "url" --- You could use a callback function in source instead, and do a manual ajax inside it, that'll allow you to also specify a error callback. E.g. `source: function(request, response) { $.ajax({ url: 'url', data: request, /* Success and error callbacks */}` -- You then use `response(myAutocompleteArrayHere)` in the success/error callbacks.

Comment: umm, I dont think I got the last comment. If the jQuery autocomplete source option is a function that calls $.ajax wont that function return before the ajax's success callback gets executed?

Comment: in function(request, response) what is request and response? can't fund anything in the docs about this...

Comment: `request` is the object containing the request information, e.g. `request.term` for the current term they're searching for, `response` is the callback function you should use to return the array with options that matched, e.g. `response(['some', 'array', 'returned', 'by', 'web service']);` -- If you click "view source" on  this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache, you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I just find myself in this situation. I wanted to clear the spinner from the textbox, and also highlight it in red, to provide visual feedback of the error. But I have 3 different textboxes in DOM that use the same function. So, you can do something like this:

```
function autocompleteSource(request,response){
    //"this" is the widget object, you can get the element that called the autocomplete function from here
    var callerTextbox = $(this.element);
    $.get(url,data).done(/*do your stuff with the data*/).fail(function(){
        highlight(callerTextbox) //That's my own function, uses jquery animation effects
        response([]); //Use an empty response for clear the textbox
    });
}
```